# Convert a Java cookie object to a String to set in httpResponse "Set-Cookie" header

Tags: java, cookies

We originally used Java's HttpsServletResponse's `addCookie(Cookie cookie)` method to add a self-created cookie to our servlet response object.  Due to some issues, I want to change this to explicitly set the cookie using `addHeader("Set-Cookie", cookieStr)`.  The cookie is constructed by passing fields to a cookie object, and I wanted to know if I can use that object to just spit out a string.  When I call `.toString()` on the cookie object, it just gives me the object reference. I know I can just construct the string, but since I already have the object, I wanted to know if there was a simple method I could call on the cookie object to parse it to a string, rather than create it myself.

Comment: If you’re running in a full Java EE container, or if you are willing to add a JAX-RS implementation (like Jersey) to your application, you can use [javax.ws.rs.core.NewCookie](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/NewCookie.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cookie class has no such method.

You could take a look at an existing implementation to judge whether you want to do that yourself. Take a look at the [Rfc6265CookieProcessor](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/782a2ba96778ce671937dc8704559e0895a52025/java/org/apache/tomcat/util/http/Rfc6265CookieProcessor.java) from Apache Tomcat. A more simple and less complete approach is [here](https://commandlinefanatic.com/cgi-bin/showarticle.cgi?article=art078). That's quite some effort.

The better way is probably to solve the issues you had with the `addCookie(Cookie cookie)` method.